# focus tooltip vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify

Boa noite pessoal.
Estou tentando dar **FOCO** a um tooltip quando o resultado de uma pesquisa feita pelo usuario retorna vazia.

Quando o usuário digita alguma coisa no campo de texto, eu faco uma validação em cima do resultado.

```
if (!result.length) { this.$store.commit('page/noSearchResult', true); }
```

No caso do resulatado vir vazio, eu seto true em uma variavel na store.
Dentro do componente que tem o tooltip, tenho um observer (watch) para essa variavel que está na store.

```
'$store.state.page.noSearchResult': 'switchAdvancedSearchFocus',
```

E quando o valor dela for **true**, eu tento dar o foco ao meu toolptip dessa forma.

```
switchAdvancedSearchFocus() {
                if (this.$store.state.page.noSearchResult) {
                    this.advancedTextSearch = true;
                    this.$refs.tooltipAdvanced.focus();
                }
            },
```

Porem tudo que tenho é esse erro:

```
Error in callback for watcher "$store.state.page.noSearchResult": "TypeError: this.$refs.tooltipAdvanced.focus is not a function"
```

Como posso solucionar isso de maneira eficaz ?

Comment: O que dá `console.log(Array.isArray(this.$refs), typeof this.$refs);` dentro desse `switchAdvancedSearchFocus`?

Comment: Boa noite Sergio, Obrigado por me ajudar. Coloquei um console exatamente como no seu comentario dentro da func: o resultado foi : false "object"

Comment: Ok, e já testaste `this.$refs.tooltipAdvanced.$el.focus()`?

Comment: Já sim. Nesse caso, nao tenho nenhuma mensagem de erro, porem o tooltip nao abre.

Comment: `this.$refs.tooltipAdvanced` pode ser um componente ou um elemento do DOM, o teu código não mostra isso... O teu código não mostra também como o tooltip é activado. Tens de mostrar mais código.... Testa `this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.tooltipAdvanced.focus(););` na esperança que quando chamares o `focus` a tooltip já esteja no DOM e que `this.$refs.tooltipAdvanced` seja um elemento do DOM